# Pandas Dataframe - How to get y given x?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe `dt` which has `x` (index) and `y` like:

```
x y      z
1 red    9
2 green  8
3 blue   7
4 black  6
5 white  5
```

I would like to retrieve `y` for a given `x`. Something like;

```
dt(3)
returns blue

dt(5)
returns white
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `dt.y[dt.x == 3]`?

Comment: [Pandas boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put column x into the index and then use the .loc operator. `dt.set_index('x').loc[x, 'y']`. If you want a faster lookup you `dt.set_index('x').at[x,'y']`